# GPA Calculator Math Issue

Tags: javascript

My loop seems to be working fine as I can enter as many inputs as requested by the user but when it comes to the calculation it errors out or prints "Your GPA is: NaN"

Just trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong as far as my math goes. Thank you in advance.

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
            <!--
            var grades = prompt("How many grades are you entering?");
            grades = Number(grades);
            var total;
            total = Number(total);
            var dec = Number(dec);
            for ( i = 0; i < grades; i++){
                prompt("Enter letter grade[A-E]: ");
            }
             if(i.equals("A")){
                 dec = 4;
                 total += dec;
             }
             else if (i.equals("B")){
                 dec = 3;
                 total += dec;
             }
             else if (i.equals("C")){
                 dec = 2;
                 total += dec;
             }
             else if (i.equals("D")){
                 dec = 1;
                 total += dec;
             }
             else if (i.equals("E")){
                 dec = 0;
                 total += dec;
             }

             var GPA;
             GPA = Number(GPA);
             GPA = total/grades;

             document.write("Your GPA is: "+ GPA);


            //-->
        </script>
```

Comment: Java removed from your title and your tags as your question has **nothing** to do with this language. Note that if you mis-tag your question you will not get the right experts in to review it, and that this may hurt your chances of getting decent help.

Comment: `var total; total = Number(total);` initialises it as `NaN`; same with `dec`. What did you actually want to do?

Comment: Sorry, new to both this website and javascript language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to believe that one needs to declare the type of a variable using a statement of the kind

```
var dec = Number(dec);
```

No, you don't. In JavaScript, variables have no types, only values do. What happens for `dec` (and `total` and `GPA`) that it has the value `undefined` which it was initialised with, and by calling the [`Number` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) you just cast it to `NaN` before reassigning it to your variable. Don't do that!

- For `grades`, the `Number()` cast is necessary because `grades` is the string returned from the `prompt()`. You want to parse it to a number and reassign that to `grades`, which is fine.
- `total` should simply be initialised with the number literal `0`.
- `dec` is not even needed.

Btw, there is no `.equals` method in JavaScript, you seem to confuse the language with Java. Just use the `==` operator. You also were missing the `var` declaration for `i`, did do nothing with the prompted grades, and had the summation put after your loop instead of dealing with every of the entered grades.

```
var grades = prompt("How many grades are you entering?");
grades = Number(grades);
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < grades; i++) {
    var grade = prompt("Enter letter grade[A-E]: ");
    if (grade == "A")
        total += 4;
    else if (grade == "B")
        total += 3;
    else if (grade == "C")
        total += 2;
    else if (grade == "D")
        total += 1;
    else if (grade == "E")
        total += 0;
}
var GPA = total/grades;
document.write("Your GPA is: "+ GPA);
```

Comment: Thanks, new to the language. Now that that's resolved. It seems to completely skip over my GPA calculation code and my document.write.

Comment: You didn't put it in the loop, your iteration value `i` (which has the same value as `grades` when the loop has ran) would be compared with those strings. I've fixed all mistakes in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Looks like I have some java habits that need to be broken.